# Python sum of ASCII values of all characters in a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, ascii

I am searching a more efficient way to sum-up the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) values of all characters in a given string, using only standard python (2.7 is preferable).

Currently I have:

```
print sum(ord(ch) for ch in text)
```

**I want to emphasize that my main focus and aspect of this question is what I wrote above.**

**The following is somewhat less important aspect of this question and should be treated as such**:

So why I am asking it?! I have compared this approach vs embedding a simple C-code function which does the same [here](http://markandclick.com/advance.html#Cboost) using PyInline, and it seems that a simple C embedded function is 17 times faster.

If there is no Python approach faster than what I have suggested (using only standard Python), it seems strange that the Python developers haven't added such an implementation in the core.

Current results for suggested answers.
On my Windows 7, i-7, Python 2.7:

```
 text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
 sum(ord(ch) for ch in text)
 >> 0.00521324663262
 sum(array.array("B", text))
 >> 0.0010040770317
 sum(map(ord, text ))
 >> 0.00427160369234
 sum(bytearray(text))
 >> 0.000864669402933

 C-code embedded:
 >> 0.000272828426841
```

Comment: Why should such a function be part of the Python core? I fail to see its general usefulness...

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: sum of ascii values of a string is frequently used when hashing a string, for example rolling hash function

Comment: hash(s) could be used instead

Comment: @Michael Only a very poor hash would do a straight sum of the values, there's usually a weighting involved. And, as pointed out, it seems better to have the higher-level interface (like `hash()`) instead, then *that* can be in C.

Comment: Writing hash functions in pure Python is a bad idea anyway (unless you're targeting PyPy, I guess).

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: lets agree to disagree ;-)

Comment: Guys, i only gave an example for hash , there are other reasons

Comment: @Michael: I wasn't disagreeing, I was just asking why such a function would be useful enough to be included in the core language.

Comment: @Michael: Sure, but a specific problem could have a better specific solution. I mean, if you want to use hashing you could use hashlib or something like that.

Comment: This question has two contentious claims: one, it compares Python-only code with embedded C code, where the embedded C code doesn't even handle a simple overflow. This comparison is therefore useless and detracts from the question. Second, the suggestion to include such a summing function in the language without giving **a single use case** is downright silly. (The hash use case doesn't count for reasons unwind explained.) Every addition to the Python core carries the maintenance and teaching burden for the foreseeable future, and needs to be covered by demonstrable use cases.

Comment: @user4815162342: My main question was, provide the fastest answer to my question using standard python 2.7, the second aspect may be unclear since i haven't provided use cases, and i will not since it is not the focus of the question!, there is no need to write such anti-comments, i see here great answers to my main question.

Comment: @Michael I concede that my tone was somewhat confrontational, but the comment was not intended as bashing. The point I was trying to get across is that the quality of the question would be improved by separating the technical question of "What is the fastest way to do X in Python?" from the dubious proposal of "X should be added to Python because doing X is currently too slow in comparison to hand-crafted C for my unspecified use case."

Comment: @user4815162342: Thanks, i will edit my question so that it will be clear, what is the main focus and aspect of this question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use an intermediate `bytearray` to speed things up:

```
>>> sum(bytearray("abcdefgh"))
804
```

This is not 17 times faster than the generator—it involves the creation of an intermediate `bytearray` and `sum` still has to iterate over Python integer objects—but on my machine it does speed up summing an 8-character string from 2μs to about 700ns. If a timing in this ballpark is still too inefficient for your use case, you should probably write the speed-critical parts of your application in C anyway.

If your strings are sufficiently large, and if you can use `numpy`, you can avoid creating temporary copies by directly referring to the string's buffer using `numpy.frombuffer`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.frombuffer("abcdefgh", "uint8").sum()
804
```

For smaller strings this is slower than a temporary array because of the complexities in numpy's view creation machinery. However, for sufficiently large strings, the `frombuffer` approach starts to pay off, and it of course always creates less garbage. On my machine the cutoff point is string size of about 200 characters.

Also, see Guido's classic essay [Python Optimization Anecdote](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/). While some of its specific techniques may by now be obsolete, the general lesson of how to *think* about Python optimization is still quite relevant.

---

You can time the different approaches with the `timeit` module:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 's = "a" * 20' 'sum(ord(ch) for ch in s)' 
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.85 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 's = "a" * 20' 'sum(bytearray(s))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.05 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'from numpy import frombuffer; s = "a" * 20' \
                      'frombuffer(s, "uint8").sum()' 
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.8 usec per loop
```

Comment: +1 , thanks, this type of answers i searched for , i will check it now

Comment: I have tested it, it is faster then i suggested, therefore it is good answer, it still slower then the embedded c-version.

Comment: Same thing works in python 3, you just have to use a bytes literal: `sum(array.array("B", b"abcdefgh"))`.

Comment: Any Python solution will always be slower than embedded C because the embedded C version is completely unsafe. In theory, the numpy-based solutions could be as fast, but in practice they have to allocate numpy's array objects which is reasonably cheap, but not free.

Comment: Nice tie-in with Python Patterns. The epilogue covers this exact case (minus the `sum` call)!

Comment: You can avoid `import array` and `sum(array.array('B', 'abcdefgh'))` and just write `sum(bytearray('abcdefgh'))` when using 2.7

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, that makes it faster and clearer. I've revised the answer to use `bytearray` throughout.

Comment: @user4815162342: Thanks i have updated the results, currently you are the winner:-)

Comment: test = ['a','b','c','d']    for i in test: print(i, sum(bytearray(i)))   results to TypeError: string argument without an encoding

Comment: @StackGuru That's because this answer from 2012 is written for Python 2.7 (as also specified in the question). Since the question speaks of "ascii values", we can assume its domain are ascii strings, so you could use `bytearray(s, 'ascii')` in Python 3.

Answer (score 12):

You can speed it up a bit (~40% ish, but nowhere near as fast as native C) by removing the creation of the generator...

Instead of:

```
sum(ord(c) for c in string)
```

Do:

```
sum(map(ord, string))
```

---

Timings:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="sum(map(ord, 'abcdefgh'))")
# TP: 1.5709713941578798
# JC: 1.425781011581421
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="sum(ord(c) for c in 'abcdefgh')")
# TP: 1.7807035140629637
# JC: 1.9981679916381836
```

Comment: +1 , Your right, it is slightly faster, but the array method is fastest, i have edited the question to present the current results.

Answer (score 3):

```
print sum(map(ord,my_string))
```

This would be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

**Prints the sum of ASCII values of the characters in the string**

First convert all your string into list with every word separated. Then use ord() function to convert every character into ascii and store them in list and then add all the list values.

```
str1 = input("Please Enter your Own String : ")
li=[] 
li[:0]=str1 
print(li)
result=[]
for i in range(len(li)):
    result.append(ord(li[i]))
    result = list(set(result))
print(result)   
final=sum(result) 
print("The sum of the your string '{}'is: {}".format(str1,final))
```